# Jquery get id of textbox that has had enter pressed?

Tags: jquery

I have multiple text boxes with ids like manual_input_1, manual_input_2, manual_input_3. I want to stop the form submiting when enter is pressed in those textboxes.

The code below does this but now I would like to know the whole id of the textbox pressing enter so I can get the box's value. e.g. manual_input_2 pressed enter, value = 1234.

```
$('[id^="manual_input_"]').keydown(function(e) {
    if(e.which == 13) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var id = ?; <--- id of textbox that pressed enter
        var value = ?; <--- value of textbox that pressed enter

        alert('Enter pressed for '+id+'\n'+
            'Value = '+value;
        )

        return false;
    }
});
```

Can this be done? Examples would be really helpful.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get the "id" with

```
var id = this.id;
```

and the value with

```
var value = this.value;
```

The jQuery event dispatch layer ensures that `this` refers to the affected element when the handler is called.

Answer (score 1):

```
var id=$(this).attr('id');
var value=$(this).val();
```

Comment: This does work, but it's not nearly as efficient as just accessing the "id" and "value" attributes of the DOM object itself.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `$(this)`:

```
$('[id^="manual_input_"]').keydown(function(e) {
    if(e.which == 13) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        var value = $(this).val();

        alert('Enter pressed for '+id+'\n'+
            'Value = '+value;
        )

        return false;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('[id^="manual_input_"]').keydown(function(e) {
if(e.which == 13) {
    e.preventDefault();

    //var id = ?; <--- id of textbox that pressed enter
    //var value = ?; <--- value of textbox that pressed enter
    var id = $(this).attr("id");
    var value = $(this).val();

    alert('Enter pressed for '+id+'\n'+
        'Value = '+value);

    return false;
}
});
```